# ID large-thorned plant growing in Turkey

Tags: species-identification, botany

Can anyone identify this plant which is growing in a friend's garden in the Uzumlu area of Turkey. It has very large spikes/thorns. I'm told it doesn't have flowers or seeds so we are wondering how it propagates itself.

[image]

Answer (score 6):

This is a palm (family [Arecaceae](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arecaceae)). Many palms have spines; I'm no expert but it looks to me like it is a member of the [*Phoenix*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phoenix_(plant)) genus, perhaps a [Cretan date palm (*Phoenix theophrasti*)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phoenix_theophrasti). Date palms do propagate themselves by seed (the pit of the date fruit). The palm in your picture, if a date palm, would be rather young, which could explain why it does not presently show flowers or fruits. Here is a photo of the spines and flowers of a Cretan date palm (by Wouter Hagens, from [Wikimedia Commons](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Phoenix_theophrasti_C.jpg)):

[image: Cretan date palm flowers]

Comment: It is very unlikely that this is _Phoenix theophrasti_, which has a very limited range. See, for example, the wikipedia link you posted: "with a very restricted distribution", giving quite specific info on where in Turkey the plant can be found.

Comment: @GeorgeWilliamRussel'spen, it may well be a different palm, but the natural range of _P. theophrasti_ (or of other species) probably isn't all that relevant, as the OP's image suggests the palm was purposely planted as part of landscaping.

Comment: It's listed as NT by the IUCN, and as stated has a very limited range. It is very unlikely that _P. theophrastii_ is planted as a part of landscaping or gardening. You would have to know about it in the first place, and then obtain a speciment. It's not a common plant, and to the best of my knowledge rarely planted.  _P. dactylifera_ and _P. canariensis_ are much more likely. And we can't tell from the picture.